# Sitecore SSO login and Silverlight drag&drop component

Tags: silverlight, sitecore, single-sign-on

I'm using Sitecore Intranet Portal and it's Silverlight file upload component and in case if AD single sign on is turned on files are not uploaded successfully.

Files are starting to upload, but stuck in the end and not added to attached files.

When SSO is turned off everything works fine.

Has anyone faced this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This problem has been resolved. You can ask about hotfix from Sitecore support. Problem related with DirectLogin.aspx. You have to add code to execute login pipeline and LogIn event onto DirectLogin.asp page.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was related with non-authenticated Silverlight requests.

We overrided UploadTarget.aspx page which accepts Silverlight file upload and changed